# import a package, use one of the classes that has been declared, throw @ Component No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java

I import a package, use one of the classes that has been declared @ Component, and then call it through the init() method, but throw a "No qualifying bean of type" error when calling it，how should I solve this problem

```java
private static PriceLibUtil priceLibUtil;
    private void init(){
        if(Objects.isNull(priceLibUtil)){
            ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextHelper.getContext();
            priceLibUtil=context.getBean(PriceLibUtil.class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Spring? Did you register the component or tell Spring to scan the package? Where is the Spring application located, i.e. in which package, and which package is the component in?

Comment: With Spring, the class is in an imported dependency and is identified by @Component in code. Not doing anything else, I have used a class in another imported package in the same way in my project. It is available, but obtaining this class throws a "No qualifying bean of type" exception

Comment: with springboot

Comment: Problem solved. The AutoConfig file‘s path  of the imported dependencies needs to be added to the/META-INF /spring.factories directory of your project so that Spring can scan the objects in the imported packages. Thank you for your kind answer

Comment: Glad it works now. For completeness note that Spring Boot normally auto detects classes in packages that are "contained" within the package the application class is in ("contained" as in "sub packages" although that's not entirely accurate). That means if your application is in package `a.b` then Spring Boot should scan packages `a.b.*` (at least within the same deployment unit). Any other packages, e.g. `a` or `a.c` need to be registered, e.g. by mentioning them in `@ComponentScan`, `@SpringBootApplication` or by registering the config classes that then trigger the component scan.